# Mouse Movement in Windows 7 - Left Click and Drag

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouse, user32

I am trying to automatically draw in a program similar to paint by simulating mouse movement and clicks with user32.dll in Windows 7.

Here's what I have and how I use it:

### Setup

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);


    [Flags]
    public enum MouseEventFlags
    {
        LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
        LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
        MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
        MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
        MOVE = 0x00000001,
        ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
        RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
        RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
    }

    public void LeftMouseDown()
    {
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0);
    }

    public void LeftMouseUp()
    {
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0);
    }
```

### When Drawing

```
            foreach (var contour in contours)
            {
                LeftMouseDown();
                foreach (var point in contour)
                {
                    var x = point.X + offsetX;
                    var y = point.Y + offsetY;
                    Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
                    //LeftMouseDown();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
                }
                LeftMouseUp();
            }
```

What I'm trying to simulate is the mouse being clicked and held, moved around to a bunch of points in each `contour` and then let up before moving on to the next `contour`.

The problem, is that this just holds the mouse button down for the first movement and then lets it up.

### TL;DR

How can I keep the mouse left click down when the mouse is being moved around programatically?

I am trying to simulate drawing in a third party app. (Microsoft LINQ's Whiteboard, the IM client.)

Comment: Don't you expect it to let up when `LeftMouseUp` is called? Your problem doesn't seem very well defined.

Comment: Is the intent to simulate drawing in your own app or control a different one?  If it's your own, why fake the mouse at all - just draw?

Comment: In a different one.  Microsoft LINQ's Whiteboard.  If I just press the mouse and move 1 px and then repeat, it generates too many lines and LINQ gets slow.  If it is all in one continuous left click it registers it as one line.

Comment: You are only simulating clicks, not moves.  Add a MouseMove() method.

Comment: @Blankasaurus, don't you mean LIN[C]'s Whiteboard? :)

Comment: @Hans Passant, How does/Why does that differ from `Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);`?

Comment: Because that doesn't go through the event input queue so doesn't generate any messages to another program.

Comment: @HansPassant, Very good to know.  You should make that an answer so I can give you a check mark and an upvote.  It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comment trail: this has not the expected result because the code only simulates mouse clicks, not mouse motion.  Moving the cursor with Cursor.Position directly changes the cursor position, bypassing the Windows input event queue.  So doesn't generate any notifications (WM_MOUSEMOVE messages) to the window that has the focus.

Fix by adding a MouseMove() method to the helper class that uses mouse_event() with MouseEventFlags.MOVE

Comment: *but* I did some simple testing, setting `Cursor.Position` does generate `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message! See my ansewer.

Comment: Can't say I remember this question after a year.  Fwiw, Windows intentionally fakes WM_MOUSEMOVE messages in certain cases, particularly when the focus changes.  Make sure you don't rely on these fake messages by accident.

Comment: Well, `Cursor.Position` calls [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx). No matter how, I believe my explanation on why OP's code don't work makes sense.

Comment: I too have the same problem but the above thing is not working. Has mouse_event been removed? How to do the left click and drag in the sendInput method? @HansPassant

Answer (score 1):

A late response, but I think the mistake you have is in calling `mouse_event`. Basically, [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reports **relative** mouse movement (when without `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`) but you pass absolute position thus making it act wrongly. Also, you should move the cursor to the position to press down the mouse button **before** performing mouse down.

So here's my fix:

```
// I changed a bit of the method signature, but that doesn't really matter
[DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern void mouse_event(MouseEventFlags flags, uint dx, uint dy, uint delta, IntPtr extraInfo);

[Flags]
enum MouseEventFlags : uint
{
    Absolute = 0x8000,
    LeftDown = 0x0002,
    LeftUp = 0x0004,
    MiddleDown = 0x0020,
    MiddleUp = 0x0040,
    Move = 0x0001,
    RightDown = 0x0008,
    RightUp = 0x0010,
    Wheel = 0x0800,
    XDown = 0x0080,
    XUp = 0x0100,
    HWheel = 0x1000,
}

public void LeftMouseDown()
{
    // Simulate left down, notice that RELATIVE movement is 0
    mouse_event(MouseEventFlags.LeftDown, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
}

public void LeftMouseUp()
{
    // Simulate left up, notice that RELATIVE movement is 0 too
    mouse_event(MouseEventFlags.LeftUp, 0, 0, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

And when moving mouse...

```
foreach (var contour in contours)
{
    // simulate mouse down AFTER cursor is moved to the first point (IMPORTANT!)
    var x = contour[0].X + offsetX;
    var y = contour[0].Y + offsetY;
    Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
    LeftMouseDown();
    foreach (var point in contour)
    {
        x = point.X + offsetX;
        y = point.Y + offsetY;
        Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
    }
    // cursor is already at the final position
    LeftMouseUp();
}
```

And a side-note, via some simple testing, setting `Cursor.Position` **does** generate `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message.