# C# Determine interval as mouse moves

Tags: c#, simulation, mousedown, mouseup

Developing an application that will simulate mouse left drag when user stop moving the mouse for one second.

How can I make the mouse left up simulation wait untill the user stops moving the mouse and it remains in same position for one second?

```
namespace AutoClicker

{

  public partial class frmClicker : Form

  {

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

    //Mouse actions

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

    public frmClicker()

    {

      InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void LeftDrag()

    {

       mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);

       Thread.Sleep(100); //How can I make the thread sleep while mouse is moving. The ms should be determined by mouse movement

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);

    }

  }  

}
```

Comment: have a look to this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097048/mouse-movement-in-windows-7-left-click-and-drag

Comment: Use a Timer from the toolbox.  Start it in a MouseMove event handler when e.Location didn't change, stop it when it did change.

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy for waiting for some thing X to ***not*** happen for a certain period of time T is as follows:

Each time X happens, set up a timer to fire after time T. (If the timer already exists, destroy it and start a new one, or restart it with a new full duration of T.)

When the timer fires, you know that time T has elapsed since the last time that X happened.

It is kind of difficult for me to understand what you are using, because you seem to be mixing Windows Forms with Win32 API (why on earth are you doing this? why are you using Win32 API instead of Windows Forms mouse events?) but under Windows Forms, the documentation for timers (together with example code) is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that will help someone who is unable to make mouse clicks using mouse. My goal is for the program to know that if the mouse stops for 1 second the mouse left button should be pressed or released.

Comment: I think there must be some feature of windows, and if not, then some (possibly free) third-party application, under the general category of "accessibility", that should be able to do anything that could possibly be asked by a person with special accessibility needs, without having to write your own.